# Load local webfonts from blob_loaded stylesheet

Tags: css, webpack

I have this stylesheet generated by WebPack:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SDC';
  src: url(/fonts/SDC.a1b82464f8ecd3973123e2140c30df02.ttf) format('truetype'), url(/fonts/SDC.af547e8d2b07993c0bc865d8c3746ac0.woff) format('woff'), url(/f68efdf3530391386b071febbff0eae2.svg#SDC) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It's loaded in my app using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/4ed04ef3-1133-417b-abe4-78501ac193e0">
```

The problem is that the fonts don't get loaded. I think the problem is the `blob` url that breaks the relative path.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is described in the [README of style-loader](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#recommended-configuration):

> Note about source maps support and assets referenced with url: when style loader is used with ?sourceMap option, the CSS modules will be generated as Blobs, so relative paths don't work (they would be relative to chrome:blob or chrome:devtools). In order for assets to maintain correct paths setting output.publicPath property of webpack configuration must be set, so that absolute paths are generated.

In your WebPack configuration, define `output.publicPath` to point to your local server (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`)

It then should look like this:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
},
```

Now, all the relative URLs well be converted to absolute ones, making them work even if loaded from `blob` protocol.

Your CSS now will be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SDC';
  src: url(http://localhost:3000//fonts/SDC.a1b82464f8ecd3973123e2140c30df02.ttf) format('truetype'), url(http://localhost:3000//fonts/SDC.af547e8d2b07993c0bc865d8c3746ac0.woff) format('woff'), url(http://localhost:3000//f68efdf3530391386b071febbff0eae2.svg#SDC) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```